# Retornar ultimos caracteres de uma string no PHP

Tags: php, string

Estou tentando incorporar algumas informações financeiras do Infomoney na minha aplicação, e na parte do Fundo de Investimento ele dá o *ranking* das principais carteiras. Só que ele retorna a seguinte *string*:

> 1º MCR-PRINCIPAL FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO EM AÇÕES +97,01%

Eu precisava explodir essa *string* em 3 partes:

1ª ranking da carteira
2ª nome da carteira
3ª índice de rentabilidade

Estou usando este script:

```
if(!$fp=fopen("https://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/fundos" , "r" )) 
{
    echo "Erro ao abrir a página de indices" ;
    exit;
}
$conteudo = '';
while(!feof($fp)) 
{ 
    $conteudo .= fgets($fp,1024);
}
fclose($fp);

$valorCompraHTML    = explode('class="numbers">', $conteudo); 
$ibovespa = trim(strip_tags($valorCompraHTML[$campo]));
$ibovespa = preg_replace(array("/\t/", "/\s{2,}/", "/\n/", "/\r/"), array("", " ", " ", " "), $ibovespa);
$ibovespa = explode(' ', $ibovespa);
$cart = trim($ibovespa[$explo]);
```

Já encontrei diversos artigos sobre retornar os primeiros caracteres de uma string. Mas como retornar os 8 últimos? Eu até achei algo na internet, mas não consegui interpretar. O código estava assim:

```
set @p = (SELECT LOCATE('+', '$xcart'));
SELECT SUBSTRING( 'xcart' , @p - 1 , @p + 5 );
```

Comment: O código em sql é para interação com o banco. Você tá usando interação com o banco para alguma coisa? Ou o seu objetivo é puramente php, sem sql?

Comment: Não estou usando nenhuma consulta não. É uma funcionalidade do infomoney. Editei a pergunta para exibir o código que estou usando

Comment: Tentei usar o código que você me passou e fiz assim: $ptx = substr($iprima, -8);  Mas está retornando o erro :"
Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\_responsivel\views\teste2.php on line 116".

Answer (score 0):

Fiz essa função pra testar e está me retornando os ultimos 8 elementos de uma string:

```
$get = $_GET['id'];

if(2==2)
{
    echo ultimos8($get);
}

function ultimos8($value)
{
    $var = $value;
    $tamanhoVar = mb_strlen($var);
    var_dump($tamanhoVar);
    $ultimos8 = substr($var, -8);
    $tamanhoVar8 = mb_strlen($ultimos8);
    var_dump($tamanhoVar8);
    var_dump($ultimos8);
}
```

A função que pega os ultimos 8 valores é a `substr`, deixei até com os `var_dumps` para você testar se quiser.

Apenas o necessário pra funcionar:

```
function ultimos8($value)
{
    $var = $value;
    $ultimos8 = substr($var, -8);

    return $ultimos8;
}
```

O que você precisa:

```
<?php
$value = '1º MCR-PRINCIPAL FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO EM AÇÕES +97,01%';

if(2==2)
{
    echo ultimos8($value);
}

function ultimos8($value)
{
    $var = $value;
    $ultimos8 = substr($var, -8);

    return $ultimos8;
}
?>
```

Comment: Porque você colocou esse 2 == 2 que eu não entendi? Mas de qualquer maneira, continua retornando a mensagem de erro "Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\_responsivel\views\teste2.php on line 126"

Comment: Coloquei o 2==2 no if apenas pra entrar no if e ficar mais claro o entendimento. O erro diz que a função substr espera uma string e foi fornecido um array, no exemplo que eu dei, a variável $value recebia uma string como valor e deu certo, verifique se você não está fornecendo um array pra função substr.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Gabriel, mas eu não sei a diferença entre um array e uma string    :/

Answer (score 0):

Olha só, você pode usar uma expressão regular para pegar as informações de forma bem mais simples, seria isso aqui:

```
<?php
  $string = "1º MCR-PRINCIPAL FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO EM AÇÕES +97,01%";
  preg_match("#(\d[^-]+)-(.*)([+-].*)#", $string, $matches);
  list($textMatch, $ranking, $nome, $indice) = $matches;

   print "1ª ranking da carteira: $ranking, 2ª nome da carteira: $nome, 3ª índice de rentabilidade: $indice";
```

Abraça, e seja feliz, `expressão regular (regex)` vai salvar sua vida sempre que você permitir rsrsrs.

Mas respondendo exatamente a sua pergunta, é só utilizar o `-`, o que ficaria assim:

```
<?php
  $string = "1º MCR-PRINCIPAL FUNDO DE INVESTIMENTO EM AÇÕES +97,01%";
  echo substr($string, -8); //Pegando apenas os últimos 8 caracters
```

Comment: Olá Flávio. Fiz o que você recomendou, mas está retornando mensagem de erro: "Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\_responsivel\teste2.php on line 277
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in D:\xampp\htdocs\_responsivel\teste2.php on line 279
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in D:\xampp\htdocs\_responsivel\teste2.php on line 279
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\_responsivel\teste2.php on line 279
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\xampp\htdocs\_responsivel\views\teste2.php on line 279"  Aonde a linha 277 define a string ($string = $iprima) e a linha 279 encontra os matches.

Comment: Isso acontece pq ele não conseguiu fazer o match da frase `1º MCR[...]` tem certeza que sua frase sempre vai seguir esse padrão de ter, 1 digito, primeira separação ser por '-'; depois uma frase; depois o índice ?

Comment: Não Flávio, este padrão não existe lá no site. Por isso que queria retornar os ultimos 8 caracteres. As 1ª e 2ª posiçõs representam o ranking (1º, 2º) e são fixas e as oito ultimas posições representam a rentabilidade, por isso 8 caracteres. 1 para o espaço (caso a rentabilidade seja maior que 99,99% e menor que 999,99%) 1 para o sinal +, 2 para os primeiros dígitos, 1 para a vírgula e 2 para a casa decimal e 1 para o sinal %

Comment: Use essa expressão então: `preg_match("#(\d[^\s]+)(.*)([+-].*)#", $string, $matches);`, mas para retornar os últimos 8 dígitos, está lá na resposta.